# Can't add to GAC using gacutil.exe

Tags: .net, ssis, gac

I have a program that uses EzAPI110, Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap, Microsoft.SQLServer.RuntimeWrap, and Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS.

I can build my program just fine but in runtime, it complains about:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=11.0.0.0,    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Sometimes the message complain about Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS instead.

I tried adding these .dll's into the GAC using gacutil which told me they were successfully installed but when I typed gacutil -i MicrosoftSqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap for instance, then it will show nothing.

I checked C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly and can't find the assemblies.

The only way around this is to use the "Copy Local" flag for these referenced DLLs but that's something I am not allowed to do due to some licensing issues.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Edit: There is a little more to the story, I have older versions of these DLL in the GAC which refuse to update for whatever reason. So I deleted these from the GAC and tried re-adding them. No luck.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Why are you trying to GAC DTSRuntimeWrap? That's installed when you install part of SQL Server.

Comment: I did actually but they were older versions. See update to my post.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this

Put a version numbering scheme in place for your GAC DLL.

Add a `<bindingRedirect>` element in your app config file so you can point to the exact version in case multiple versions exist.

Hope this helps.